# Were there any broken laws, unlawful orders or violation of rights during this traffic stop?

Tags: united-states, california, police, traffic, arrest

[Here is a video of a traffic stop in Sacramento, California.](http://youtube.com/watch?v=VfJ1yIQsoVw)

Questions:

1. Did the police or the detainee break any laws?
2. Did the police issue any unlawful orders?
3. In particular, was the order to roll the window down at 2:15 a lawful order?
4. Did the police act lawfully by pointing a gun at the detainee?
5. Did the police act lawfully by arresting the detainee?
6. Did the police violate any of the detainee's rights at any time during the incident?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Did the police or the detainee break any laws?

I can’t see any from the police. The detainee did when he demanded to speak the the police officer’s supervisor instead of following the directions given. Of course, it was alleged that laws were broken that initiated the stop but we didn’t see those.

> 2. Did the police issue any unlawful orders?

Not that I can see.

> 3. In particular, was the order to roll the window down at 2:15 a lawful order?

I can’t see that it wouldn’t be - when questioned the officer explained that it was a safety precaution, presumably it allowed better visibility and freedom of action.

> 4. Did the police act lawfully by pointing a gun at the detainee?

Probably - the detainee had stated that there was a firearm in the vehicle and an intention to cease cooperation.

> 5. Did the police act lawfully by arresting the detainee?

Ditto.

> 6. Did the police violate any of the detainee's rights at any time during the incident?

Not that I can see.